# different keyboard layout key bindings in emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm using two keyboard layouts - one for my mother-tongue language, and the other is english.
Problem is when I switch to my mother-tongue language keyboard layout, and try to perform keybinding commands.

Is there an easy way to tell emacs to treat all commands (C-key,M-key etc) using the default, English-layout bindings?

I've seen this question:
[Emacs determining keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813648/emacs-determining-keyboard-layout)
in which one answer simulates all keys to their according English-layout keys, but it is mentioned it eats up loading time, and the code is long, unreadable and thus probably error prone to me.

Help would me appreciated.

Comment: tricky, The nice work around I use, "using english keyboard while I am on emacs and if I want to write my language, I use emacs inbuilt input system". `C-\` or `M-x toggle-input-method`.

Comment: well, I have meta-shift for that (I though all multi-langual layouts use that key?), but in the midst of writing I usually automatically reach for a command (e.g. save) only to find out that it's not available. in some cases, the keys are swapped - q, for example, turns into /, and then it becomes unpredictable altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two layouts use completely different characters, then you can simply let Emacs try "the other character".  E.g. if one key is `b` in US layout but `и` in the other layout, you can use:

```
(define-key function-key-map [?и]       [?b])
(define-key function-key-map [?\C-и]    [?\C-b])
(define-key function-key-map [?\M-и]    [?\M-b])
(define-key function-key-map [?\M-\C-и] [?\M-\C-b])
```

OTOH if the two layout end up swapping some characters, Emacs would really need to know which layout is active in order to know whether or not to remap the key.  I don't know enough about keyboard handling to know how to let Emacs tell you which layout is in use currently.

Comment: Would be wonderful to have something more global, like a function to define "for all command keys, always use English layout"

Comment: @EladR: All keys are command keys.  So you're basically asking for Emacs to always use the US layout, and then in `self-insert-command` somehow recover the non-US layout.  Maybe that could be done in some cases by attaching the non-US-layout version of the key to each event.

Answer (score 6):

Many layout managers allow applications (or even windows) to keep their own layout. Use English layout for Emacs, to write in you mother tongue, switch the input method (<kbd>C-\</kbd>).

Comment: The first time you will have to chose your language but after that it automatically switches between the default (English) and your chosen language. It is a relief that I don't have to choose my input method every time I switch :) However if you close and open Emacs you will have to choose the input. Then again the input method could probably be set in the init file of emacs.